# Are the operators of the four basic operations of arithmetic binary operators?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

1. Supposing I have a subtraction (multiplication and division)  of 3 or more numbers, e.g., 20 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 1, will the subtraction end up being done **in pairs**, i.e., the - operator is `binary` and therefore **only** supports **2 operands at a time**?
2. Would the multiplication (x) and division (/) operators also be `binary operators`, i.e., will they operate **only** on **2 operands at the same time**?

For example:

9 x 3 x 2 x 2 x 4 -> Will the operation be performed with only 2 operands at a time?

100 / 2 / 5 / 2 -> Will the operation be performed with only 2 operands at a time?
I am new to algebra.

My question is just to understand **what happens "in detail"** when we have more than 2 operands in these 3 basic arithmetic operations, I am new to algebra

Comment: $9\times 3\times 2\times 2\times 4 = (((9\times 3)\times 2)\times 2)\times 4$.  Multiplication and addition is associative and so for the sake of brevity we leave out the parentheses.  For subtraction and division, although not associative, it is still beneficial for us to leave out the parentheses to make things easier to read and write and just have a standard convention for how to read things... namely from left-to-right... so $20-3-2-3-1$ is to be interpreted as $(((20-3)-2)-3)-1$.

Comment: Could you go through the effort of also defining a ternary or quaternary operator or $n$-ary operator in general for these?  Sure... there is nothing explicitly wrong with doing so, but to emphasize this isn't strictly necessary to do.  Defining as binary operators and outlining the convention for how to read and interpret what is written in this way is plenty sufficient.

Comment: For the subtraction , we clearly have the convention that it is calculated "from the left" , if there are no parantheses. But this is not always the case, for exponentiation , the convention is to calculate "from the right"

Comment: Hi @JMoravitz, so, can we say that the subtraction, multiplication and division operators can have *several operands* but **only** operate on 2 at a time, i.e. they are binary operands?

Comment: You are focusing on specific nuances that don't matter to other people.  If you want to "operate on more than 2 at a time"... what does that change?  Does it change the final result of the calculation to you?  I should hope not.  If it helps you sleep better at night, then you can insist on performing only operations involving two operands at a time.  If it helps you sleep better at night, then you can be more loose with your definitions and define things that allow several operands.  *It doesn't matter!*  All that matters is that the definitions are usable and you get the same results.

Comment: I can when performing mental arithmetic say very quickly that $120 / 5 / 4 / 3$ is equal to $2$  (*recall that $5!=120$*) by thinking of all of these simultaneously and performing one large simultaneous calculation that involves all pieces in my mind at once.  There is nothing wrong with that, and there is nothing wrong with formalizing that either.  Of course, I could *also* say that this is $((120 / 5) / 4) / 3$ and perform each calculation in succession.  There is nothing wrong with that either.  The point is that we define mathematics so that it is useful for us to solve problems we have.

Comment: It so happens that at the time of defining things formally, *it is common* to stop at defining things as binary operators because that is all we *need* to do.  We can perform all arithmetic we want with this definition.  Could we go further?  Yes!  Does it let us do more than we could before?  No, not really.  We might be able to do things "more efficiently" or in a "more aesthetically pleasing way", and that might be enough reason for you to choose to do this... it doesn't matter in the end though.  We know how the final result should be, so long as you get that result that is what matters.

Comment: My question is just to understand what happens "in detail" when we have more than 2 operands in these 3 basic arithmetic operations, I edited the question @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1):

Formally speaking for instance in the context of Peano Axioms, one begins with the natural numbers. In this case addition is a binary operation $+ : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined as repeated successor ($S : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$). In particular one defines the function "add $n$ to an arbitrary $m$" recursively for all "$n$" and then a new function which simply takes in two inputs $n$ and $m$; i.e., effectively a binary operation.

Multiplication is defined recursively as repeated addition and thus is also binary.

Subtraction is usually defined for the integers and bigger number systems in terms of addition between natural numbers and is thus also binary.

Division is usually defined for even bigger numbers systems (although nothing prevents one from dividng in the integers as long as one knows that not all results will be integers themselves) in terms of multiplication and is thus also binary.

Having said this, it is a matter of conventions. I suppose one could come up with different definitions for these operations which are not necessarily binary. However, for most conventional practical purposes there seem to be no obvious advantage in doing so.

PS: Note, as already pointed out in the comments, that thanks to the commutativity and associativity of these operations, their binary nature is not particularly important.

Comment: Hi @Promethèus, do binary operation and binary operator mean the same thing, i.e. they operate **only** on 2 values at a time?

Comment: As far as I know, the words "operator" and "operations" are usually used in different contexts for different things. In this context, when talking about "+,-,x,/" it is common to call these operations.

Comment: I understand, so, are they called binary operations because they only operate on 2 operands at a time even though there are more operands? @Promethèus

Comment: Correct. They are called binary operations because they take two inputs and give one output. A ternary operation would take three inputs instead. When we write $2+2+2$ we can do so because $(2+2) + 2$ and $2 + (2+2)$ are exactly the same thing by associativity of addition. But, formally and conventionally, the operation is defined just for two inputs at the time.

Comment: "*But, formally and conventionally, the operation is defined just for two inputs at the time.*" - This is the main question, finally someone understood it. So, do subtraction, multiplication and division also operate with 2 inputs at the same time formally and conventionally? @Promethèus

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the answer, the usual construction of number systems defines these operation as binary operations.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question in your title, yes, each of them is a binary operator. But most of the questions you pose in the body of your post are of the form “Will it be performed…?” And the answer to that question depends on context. In most contexts, the canonical order of operations is implied.

In any event, the reason they’re called binary operators is that they always (always) have exactly two operands. So consider the general form

> $x_0 \star_1 x_1 \star_2 \cdots \star_n x_n$.

Syntactically, it is an alternating sequence of operators $\star_i$ interleaved with operands $x_j$. In principle, the $n$ operations could be evaluated in any of $n!$ orders. When any particular operation $\star_i$ is evaluated, its first operand is either $x_{i-1}$ or the value of a (previously evaluated) subexpression involving $x_{i-1}$. Likewise, $\star_i$’s other operand is either $x_i$ or the value of a subexpression involving it.

The evaluation always involves successively applying binary operations to pairs of operands (each of which may itself be the value of a nested subexpression).

Comment: Hi@Paul Tanenbaum, regarding the other questions are just to exemplify, my question basically is: can we say that the subtraction, multiplication and division operators can have *several operands* but **only operate on 2 at a time**, i.e. they are binary operands?

Comment: You **can** say it, but only if you define your terms accordingly. Does one (standardly) say it? No.

Comment: I edited the question @Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: You **don’t** “have more than 2 operands” for any of the operators. As has been explained, an expression like $3+5 - 2$ is understood to mean $(3+5) - 2$, in other words it is a difference, a subtraction of one quantity from another, where the quantity being subtracted from just happens to be a sum.

Comment: I understand, so, why do you say this "In answer to the question in your title, yes, each of them is a binary operator. "? @Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: Because they are. What is it about that proposition that puzzles you? To extend my example, in $3+5-2$, the two operands of $+$ are 3 and 5, and the two operands of $-$ are $(3+5)$ and 2.

Comment: "*What is it about that proposition that puzzles you?*" - If the operation were 3 + 2 + 2, would it still add "all 3 at once" or how? @Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: The convention is that it would group from left to right. Thus $(3+2) + 2$. As it happens, addition is associative, so the expression has the same value as $3 +(2+2)$. In any event, you’ve got a bunch of binary operations applied to nested results of other binary operations.

Comment: For an expression of the form $x_0 \star_1 x_1 \star_2 \cdots \star_n x_n$, you can associate in any of $n!$ ways, but each operation $\star_i$ has exactly two operands.

Comment: "*In any event, you’ve got a bunch of binary operations applied to nested results of other binary operations*" - Actually this sentence answers my main question (maybe I couldn't express it the right way in my question post). That sentence means that these 4 basic arithmetic operators **always** operate on 2 operands "by nature" (in themselves, by definition), no matter how many operands the "complete expression" has, right? @Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: Then I’ll elevate it to an answer, and if it does the trick, you can indicate so.

Comment: Excellent, please edit my question and put these details (and if possible more) in your answer to mark it as the better one, please @Paul Tanenbaum

Comment: I edited my answer. I cannot edit **your** question. If you wish, **you* can do that.

Comment: Does the star symbol represent the operator and the x represents the operand? @Paul Tanenbaum